# Using django formset with crispyforms is making pages slow

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I was using  django formset with crispy forms. The page was opening slow if 1-2 people opens it. But when 100 people try to open the page lots of people couldn't open the page.

Formset is defined as below :

```
StudentClassLessonAttendanceFormsetFactory = modelformset_factory(StudentClassLessonAttendance, extra=0, fields=('att', 'student',))
formset = StudentClassLessonAttendanceFormsetFactory(queryset=StudentClassLessonAttendance.objects.filter(semester_id=semester, dateadded=today, lessonhour=hour, cls_id=courseteacherobject['cls_id'], course_id=courseteacherobject['course_id']))
helper = TableInlineHelper()
return render(request, 'edit-daily-attendance.html', {'formset': formset, 'helper': helper, 'lessonhour': lessonhour, 'courseclassyear': courseteacherobject['cls__year'], 'courseclassname': courseteacherobject['cls__name']})
```

After that i stopped using formset and crispy-forms and created the form manually in template. Now the page is opening fast and page can be opened by everybody. The problem is solved but i couldnt figure it out why the page freeze and opens slow when i use formset with crispyforms when the page is called by lots of people at the same time.

I am using django 1.9.5 and python 2.7.5 on linux Centos.

Comment: I dont know how to solve this but you could try using django-debug-toolbar https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and see which are the differences between your hardcoded form and the one generated with formset.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I havent used toolbar. It will be helpfull. I will use it.